# my app Transplanted from 480*800 into480*854,systemUI error

Tags: android

I have an phone app that runs well. Nowaday I have move it to an new place then something went wrong.

My app transplanted from 480*800 into 480*854, systemUI says error and Status bar can't see anything.

I don't know where is the problem is?

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.view.View

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.view.View

11-08 10:43:32.879: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.879: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.879: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.879: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.879: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.879: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.879: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.879: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.879: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.879: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.879: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.879: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:32.928: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.069: E/AwesomePlayer(35): AwesomePlayer::setDataSourcel out haveAuido = 1, havevideo = 0 
11-08 10:43:33.129: E/AwesomePlayer(35): AwesomePlayer::setDataSourcel out haveAuido = 1, havevideo = 0 
11-08 10:43:33.159: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.159: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.159: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.159: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.159: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.159: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.159: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.159: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.159: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.159: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.159: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.159: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:33.189: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:34.599: E/dalvikvm(230): [DVM] mmap return base = 45bf6000
11-08 10:43:35.948: E/TwelveKeyDialer(230): twelvekeydialer : one. view

11-08 10:43:35.958: E/TwelveKeyDialer(230): twelvekeydialer : after view
11-08 10:43:36.299: E/dalvikvm(160): [DVM] mmap return base = 47728000
11-08 10:43:36.429: E/Zygote(34): writeInt++369
11-08 10:43:36.429: E/Zygote(34): writeInt--369
11-08 10:43:36.439: E/ZygoteProcess(72): readInt++
11-08 10:43:36.439: E/ZygoteProcess(72): readInt--: 369
11-08 10:43:36.659: E/PhoneStatesMgrService(160): handleMessage no item to handle
11-08 10:43:37.149: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.149: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.149: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.149: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.149: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.149: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.149: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.149: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.149: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.149: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.149: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.149: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.209: E/Zygote(34): writeInt++381
11-08 10:43:37.219: E/ZygoteProcess(72): readInt++
11-08 10:43:37.219: E/Zygote(34): writeInt--381
11-08 10:43:37.219: E/ZygoteProcess(72): readInt--: 381
11-08 10:43:37.259: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.259: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.259: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.259: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.259: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.259: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.259: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.259: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.259: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.259: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.259: E/AudioPolicyManagerBase(35): unknown stream type
11-08 10:43:37.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is problem in your layout file.   for 480x854  you can create separate folder for layout as    layout-hdpi-854x480